# crash saving my profile when image don't exist iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having some trouble when I press the  button save to edit the profile :

for example the image don't exist and when I press save button, it's crash, please find below my code? what am I missing ?

Once I remove the condition if the profile image don't exist my code work..

```js
 let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageUser.image!, 0.0)

 //---------------------------------------
 // Check if all fields are empty
 //---------------------------------------


 if (Name.text!.isEmpty && Username.text!.isEmpty && website.text!.isEmpty && aboutUser.text!.isEmpty && emailUser.text!.isEmpty && phoneUser.text!.isEmpty && genderUser.text!.isEmpty && (profileImageData == nil)) {
   print("error")

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are force unwrapping the contents of the variable `imageUser.image` in the first line of code you posted.  When you do this, it will crash your application if the value of `imageUser.image` is `nil`.  I suggest you check out the section on [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) in [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.0)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).

If `imageUser.image` can be nil, this is a more correct version of your code.  Note the use of an `if let` statement to safely unwrap the contents of `imageUser.image`.  It's worth mentioning that every place you're using a `!` in your code below, will crash if that value you're using it on is `nil` (which is why this code only more correct and not fully correct).

```
if let profileImage = imageUser.image {
    let profileImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.0)

    //---------------------------------------
    // Check if all fields are empty
    //---------------------------------------


    if (Name.text!.isEmpty && Username.text!.isEmpty && website.text!.isEmpty && aboutUser.text!.isEmpty && emailUser.text!.isEmpty && phoneUser.text!.isEmpty && genderUser.text!.isEmpty && (profileImageData == nil)) {
        print("error")

    }
}
else {
    print("image was nil")
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so how to check if the image is not existing or not ?

Comment: I updated with some code, but you should really read the referenced parts of the language documentation.  Optional values are an important part of Swift that you must know about.